# Exporting to excel when there are special characters in the data ( French descriptions)

Tags: export-to-excel

I am exporting data to excel file using Excel query table. There will be a text file with the data containing many rows, each cell is separated by | character. I am dumping the data to excel file using the following code

```
         try
        {
            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;
            oXL.UserControl = false;
            //Get a new workbook.
            oWBook = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(strFilename, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false));
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWBook.ActiveSheet;
            oSheet.Activate();

            //Create header row 2
            oXL.ReferenceStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1;
            Excel.Range oRange2 = oSheet.get_Range("A2", "A2");
            oRange2.FormulaR1C1 = HeaderLine1;

            //Create header row 2
            oRange2 = oSheet.get_Range("A3", "A3");
            oRange2.FormulaR1C1 = HeaderLine2;

            oRange2 = oSheet.get_Range("A" + StartRowNumber.ToString().Trim(), Missing.Value);
            var temp = oSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" + TextFileName, oRange2, Missing.Value);

            temp.Name = TextFileName.ToUpper().Replace(".TXT", "");
            temp.PreserveFormatting = true;
            temp.AdjustColumnWidth = false;
            temp.TextFileStartRow = 1;
            temp.TextFileParseType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited;
            temp.TextFileTextQualifier = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote;
            temp.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = false;
            temp.TextFileTabDelimiter = true;
            temp.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = false;
            temp.TextFileCommaDelimiter = false;
            temp.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = false;
            temp.TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|";
            temp.TextFilePlatform = 1252;//65001;//1252;//65001;//1200;
            //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page
            temp.TextFileColumnDataTypes = GetDataType(ColumnDataType);
            temp.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = true;
            temp.Refresh(false);

            //temp.Connection.ToString();
            temp.Delete();



            oXL.ReferenceStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1;
            oWBook.Save();
            oWBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oWBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        }
        finally
        {
            oXL.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
            oSheet = null;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWBook);
            oWBook = null;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
            oXL = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
```

When the text file contains some special characters( Ex French words) it will not display as they are when the excel file is opened after generating....

Can anyone help to solve this problem ?

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: I am a Java programmer, so I am not familiar with the code you have provided. However, this seems to be an encoding problem.
Set your encoding to the right one. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I need to use encoding. But I don't see any option(property) for assigning the encoding type to the temp object in this code. I need to use this code for exporting  Is there any way in this code where I can assign the encoding type while exporting ?